# rubocop how do you fix Missing magic comment

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rubocop

I have a library of ruby code, and to look for defects I run

```
$ rubocop
```

And I get

```
$ rubocop
Inspecting 153 files
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCWCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCWCCCCCCCWWCCCCC

Offenses:

Gemfile:1:1: C: Missing magic comment # frozen_string_literal: true.
source "https://rubygems.org"
```

What modifications are required in my Gemfile to make rubocop not complain?

Comment: Does this help? Definition: https://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/58-magic-instructions.html, Style guide: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#magic-comments

Comment: Can you share a source file with errors?

Comment: the first line of the file is source "https://rubygems.org"

Comment: why is this downvoted?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just add

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
```

to the first line of each Ruby file. Or run

```
rubocop -a
```

to allow Rubocop to fix all offenses automatically that it is able to fix.

Btw. I like Rubocop and use it myself, but I wouldn't call the things it finds *defects*. I see the list more like suggestions or reasons for a discussion with my co-workers.

Comment: Instead of all files, ` rubocop -a` is only `Inspecting 2 files` and only changed the `Rakefile`. How do I make rubocop scan the whole project? I already tried things with `*` and `**` without success

Comment: @Cadoiz `rubocop -a` will fix all safely auto-correctable offenses in your project, depending on your Rubocop's configuration. If it does not, then you might want to consider opening a new question with more details about your project, your configuration and the types of offenses that command does not fix.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to be more specific and run `rubocop` for *only* `# frozen_string_literal: true` you can use the `--only` flag option:

> Run only the specified cop(s) and/or cops in the specified departments.

To view those files:

```
rubocop --only Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment
```

To autocorrect those specific files use the `-a` flag (as mentioned [in a previous, now accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47029997/4575793)):

```
rubocop --only Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment -A
```

You can view more information about autocorrect [here](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/0.89/usage/auto_correct.html).

Comment: Also, to correct the "Add an empty line after magic comments." offenses that running this command will likely produce you can use this:      rubocop --only "Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment, Layout/EmptyLineAfterMagicComment" -A

Comment: The letter '-A' must be upper case, as frozen_string_literal is not always safe - or rubocop can not verify wether it is really safe for the file. '-a' is only for safe corrections, see docs linked in answer.

Comment: I disagree with @FallenAngel as upper-case `-A` gives me `invalid option: -A
For usage information, use --help`. I'm using `ruby 2.6.6p146`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to ignore it, add to your `.rubocop.yml`

```
Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment:
  Enabled: false
```

But may be you want to know [what "Magic comment" is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799296/what-does-the-comment-frozen-string-literal-true-do), especially if you're using Ruby 2.x

Answer (score 2):

Try running Rubocop with the `-D` option:

```
rubocop -D
Inspecting 1 file
C

Offenses:

spec/rails_helper.rb:1:1: C: Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment: Missing magic comment # frozen_string_literal: true.
require 'spec_helper'
^
```

Adding `-D` will cause Rubocop to print the name of the cop that was violated, in this case `Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment`. You can then search for that cop [in the Rubocop documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment):

> This cop is designed to help upgrade to Ruby 3.0. It will add the comment `# frozen_string_literal: true` to the top of files to enable frozen string literals. Frozen string literals will be default in Ruby 3.0. The comment will be added below a shebang and encoding comment. The frozen string literal comment is only valid in Ruby 2.3+.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
bundle exec rubocop --parallel -A
```

Auto-fix all files

Comment: You’ve posted this same answer to another question. Please refrain from doing that. If questions are duplicates, they should be flagged as such. Also, I left some comments on your previous answer which also apply here—such as why you prefer this answer over the existing answers already provided.