# Ruby: magic comments "frozen_string_literal: true" vs "immutable: string"

Tags: ruby

In ruby one can freeze all constant strings in a file via two different magic comments at the beginning of a file:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
```

and

```
# -*- immutable: string -*-
```

I have no idea what the differences are.
Are there any?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799296/what-does-the-comment-frozen-string-literal-true-do#37799399

Comment: The difference is that the first one works and the second one has nothing to do with Ruby and thus doesn't do anything.#

Answer (score 7):

The 1st syntax is the magic comment for Ruby 2.3+ versions to freeze string literals, otherwise you have to use the String method like this:

```
'hello world!'.freeze
```

The 2nd syntax is not implemented in Ruby, however it is the [way that variables are specified for files in the Emacs text editor](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html).

For example, the following comment in Emacs would declare that the file is a Ruby file and needs Ruby syntax highlighting, and that the variable `immutable` is set to the value `string`.

```
# -*- mode: ruby; immutable: string -*-
```

After searching around, it looks like that does nothing and is not used by any Ruby syntax highlighting mode.

So you do not need the 2nd syntax.

Comment: are you sure 1st version works in Ruby < 2.3 ?? , I tested 2.1.2 and it does not.

Comment: @lacostenycoder apparently the feature was targeted for 2.1 but ended up being in 2.2: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9278 but it looks like it's 2.3+ only :/

Answer (score 3):

Digging for anything on the 2nd version, it looks like they had the same intention but the 2nd magic comment syntax does not to appear to have been adopted [as of Ruby 2.1.0](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/487).

The first version `# frozen_string_literal: true` was adopted in Ruby 2.3.0

I tried the latter version in a few versions of Ruby but didn't work. I would guess it should not be used or trusted to work in any version of `>= 2.3` but probably no versions support it. In fact, I was not able to find any reference to that version in the open source code on GitHub [searching that syntax](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/search?q=immutable%3A%20string&unscoped_q=immutable%3A%20string).