# Ruby frozen string comment syntax difference

Tags: ruby

There are two ways of enabling all strings in a file to be implicitly frozen<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37799399/517868)</sup>.

```
# frozen-string-literal: true
# frozen_string_literal: true
```

Is there a difference between these two syntaxes?

Thanks!

Comment: `# frozen-string-literal: true` is just a normal Ruby comment. Read this for `# frozen_string_literal: true` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37799399/645886

Answer (score 2):

The answer you link to never uses the magic comment `# frozen-string-literal: true` only `# frozen_string_literal: true`. The difference is that only the latter will work.

The other way to enable frozen string literals is to run the application with the `--enable=frozen-string-literal` flag.