# What does frozen mean for dataclasses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-dataclasses

What's the difference between `@dataclass(frozen=True)` and `@dataclass(frozen=False)`? When should I use which?

Comment: Do you want instances of your data class to be mutable or immutable?

Comment: @khelwood That's the question... What's the difference between mutable and immutable instances? I know that strings and tuples are immutable. So do I have to set frozen True if I'm using using Strings or Tuples?

Comment: Immutable means you can't change the attributes or characteristics of an object after it's initialised. [What is immutability?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/622664/3890632)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

In Python, "frozen" means an object cannot be modified. For example, consider `set` and `frozenset`:

```py
>>> s = set((1, 2, 3))
>>> s
{1, 2, 3}
>>> s.add(4)
>>> s
{1, 2, 3, 4}
>>> fs = frozenset((1, 2, 3))
>>> fs
frozenset({1, 2, 3})
>>> fs.add(4)
...
AttributeError: 'frozenset' object has no attribute 'add'
```

Likewise, creating a `dataclass` with `frozen=True` means its instances are frozen and cannot be changed.

Be aware that `frozen` only applies to the dataclass instance itself – a `frozen` dataclass can contain mutable items such as lists, and a regular dataclass can contain frozen/immutable items such as tuples.

---

The point of frozen objects is to avoid accidental modification, and to guarantee a consistent value.

- The former is advantageous to avoid bugs. When an object is not intended to be modified, making it `frozen` reveals accidental modification via an immediate error.
- The latter allows use as immutable object, for example the keys of a `dict`. A `frozen` dataclass is by default hashable and suitable as a `dict` key.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Frozen:
    x: int
    y: int

named_points = {Frozen(0, 0): "Origin"}
```

Note that hashability does not just depend on the dataclass but is recursive – a `frozen` dataclass containing a `list` is not hashable, because the `list` is not hashable.

Comment: is there a dataclass so frozen that we cannot even change the default values when instantiating?

Comment: Actually we can. Either by putting init=False in the decorator or by field(init=False). Together with frozen