# Javascript Lodash replace array with another

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash, immutability

I'm trying to manipulate an array like this:

```
data = [
   {
      "id":"1",
      "items":[
         {
            "title":"item 1"
         },
         {
            "title":"item 2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "items":[
         {
            "title":"item2 1"
         },
         {
            "title":"item2 2"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I need, for example, to push another array:

```
      [
         {
            "title":"item new 1"
         },
         {
            "title":"item new 2"
         }
      ]
```

inside data[0].items and obtain:

```
data = [
       {
          "id":"1",
          "items":[
             {
            "title":"item new 1"
         },
         {
            "title":"item new 2"
         }
          ]
       },
       {
          "id":"2",
          "items":[
             {
                "title":"item2 1"
             },
             {
                "title":"item2 2"
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
```

...how can I do this **maintaining immutability**, for example with **Lodash**?
Not understand anding how to change only a specific sub object in a data structure.
Somebody have suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: `data[0].items = [{ "title": "item new 1" }, { "title": "item new 2" }]`

Comment: Sorry, No. I know how to access to the correct obj (es. `data[0].items = [];
data[0].items.push(newArray)`).
My problem is that I need to preserve immutability, that's why I'm searching a way with Lodash, thanks

Comment: What do you mean with _"preserve immutability"_? There is no immutability in your code. How do you want to modify an immutable object?

Comment: Are you looking for [`Lodash#cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep)

Comment: I voted to close because the question is unclear.

Comment: from the question: _**maintaining immutability**_ --> OP (@WolF), this typically means that the original object or array being manipulated must remain as-is and changes are made on a copy of the original. Is this how you intended it? So, when you immutably add some new information to an existing object/array, you get a new object/array (while the original remains as-is / not-mutated).

Comment: @jsN00b Immutability usually means that changes are ignored (e.g. string: `let s = 'abc'; s[1] = 'd';`) or cause an error (e.g. [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)). It has nothing to do with deep copies or pure functions.

Answer (score -1):

Presented below is one possible way to immutably add given array into a particular index `"items"` prop.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const immutableAdd = (aIdx, addThis, orig) => {
  const newData = structuredClone(orig);
  newData[aIdx].items = addThis;
  return newData;
};

const data = [{
    "id": "1",
    "items": [{
        "title": "item 1"
      },
      {
        "title": "item 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "items": [{
        "title": "item2 1"
      },
      {
        "title": "item2 2"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const addThisArr = [{
    "title": "item new 1"
  },
  {
    "title": "item new 2"
  }
];

console.log('immutableAdd result: ', immutableAdd(0, addThisArr, data));
console.log('original data: ', data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

- Use `structuredClone()` to deep-clone existing `data` array
- Navigate to the `aIdx` of the cloned-array
- Assign the given array (to be added) into `aIdx`'s `items` prop

**NOTE**

This solution does not use **lodash** as it is not mandatory (to use *lodash*) to perform immutable operations.

Comment: _"immutably add"_ is an oxymoron. Either it's immutable or you can add something.

Comment: @jabaa insofar as reallocating memory for the array `data` goes, the principle underlying `immutability` is held by not altering the array.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to maintain the immutability of original data, just map the content of original data to the new data as you want, and wrap your logic into a pure function to improve readability.

```js
const dataOriginal = [{
    "id": "1",
    "items": [{
        "title": "item 1"
      },
      {
        "title": "item 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "items": [{
        "title": "item2 1"
      },
      {
        "title": "item2 2"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const dataNew = createDataWithSomethingNew(dataOriginal, [{
    "title": "item new 1"
  },
  {
    "title": "item new 2"
  }
])

function createDataWithSomethingNew(data, props) {
  return data.map(function changeItemsOfId1ToProps(value) {
    if (value.id === '1') {
      return {
        id: value.id,
        items: props
      }
    } else {
      return value
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with immutability.

Answer (score -2):

`lodash` has a method [_.update](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#update) can modify object with the correct `path` in string provided.

Another method [_.cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) can copy you object deeply. So that change in the pre-copied object will not affect the cloned object.

Finally use a deep freeze function to call `Object.freeze` recursively on the cloned object to make it [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/622773/10100812).

```
var data = [
   {
      "id":"1",
      "items":[
         {
            "title":"item 1"
         },
         {
            "title":"item 2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "items":[
         {
            "title":"item2 1"
         },
         {
            "title":"item2 2"
         }
      ]
   }
]

var clonedData = _.cloneDeep(data) // copy the full object to avoid modify the source data

// update the data of that path '[0].items' in clonedData
_.update(clonedData, '[0].items', function(n) {
  return [
    {
      "title":"item new 1"
    },
    {
      "title":"item new 2"
    }
  ]
})

// provide object immutability
 const deepFreeze = (obj1) => {
    _.keys(obj1).forEach((property) => {
      if (
        typeof obj1[property] === "object" &&
        !Object.isFrozen(obj1[property])
      )
        deepFreeze(obj1[property])
    });
    Object.freeze(obj1)
  };

deepFreeze(clonedData)


data[2] = {id: 3} // data will be changed
data[1].items[2] = {title: "3"} // and also this one

clonedData[2] = {id: 3} // nothing will be changed
clonedData[1].items[2] = {title: "3"} // and also this one

console.log(`data:`, data);
console.log(`clonedData:`, clonedData);
```

[Runkit Example](https://runkit.com/edw1n/626e881b301a2c000865ea35)

Comment: _"Another method _.cloneDeep can provided you a deep level immutable object."_ `_.cloneDeep` doesn't provide an immutable object.

Comment: @jabaa Thanks for pointing the out. I never know that I was doing it wrong all the time learned from some YouTube tutorial. Sadly this one is closed and being down voted, but at least I have learned something. :)

Comment: You've learned from a video that `_.cloneDeep` returns an immutable object? Do you have a link?

Comment: IIRC, it was a `Redux` tutorial, but I can remember exactly which one. It taught that `spread operator` on an array or object can make it immutable. That's why I wrongly believe that cloneDeep can make object immutable.

Comment: Spread operator can't make an object immutable.